# How to make Django LiveServerTestCase log requests

Tags: django

Django has a feature to [log each http request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#django-request). Eg.:

`INFO 2017-08-31 11:52:40,725 arnaud basehttp "GET /design/projects/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3852`

Unfortunately, it seems to be disabled when running a `LiveServerTestCase`. In order to ease the debugging of my end-to-end tests, I would like this feature to remain activated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, this behavior doesn't seem configurable. I couldn't find any doc on the subject, and resorted to dive inside Django.

### Solution

(**disclaimer**: this is unofficial, therefore brittle)

Override the `server_thread_class` attribute of your `LiveServerTestCase`

```
from django.core.servers.basehttp import ThreadedWSGIServer, WSGIRequestHandler
from django.test.testcases import LiveServerTestCase, LiveServerThread

class End2End(LiveServerTestCase):

    class VersboseLiveServerThread(LiveServerThread):
        def _create_server(self):
            return ThreadedWSGIServer((self.host, self.port), WSGIRequestHandler, allow_reuse_address=False)

    server_thread_class = VersboseLiveServerThread
```

### A bit more details

This solution and the feeling that there is no way to configure that behavior properly stem from observing how `LiveServerTestCase` is built (Django 1.11):

```
class LiveServerTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    # [...]
    server_thread_class = LiveServerThread

class LiveServerThread(threading.Thread):
    # [...]
    def _create_server(self):
        # an extension point returning the WSGIRequestHandler would have been nice :)
        return ThreadedWSGIServer((self.host, self.port), QuietWSGIRequestHandler, allow_reuse_address=False)

class QuietWSGIRequestHandler(WSGIRequestHandler):
    def log_message(*args):
        pass
```

Comment: Note that in the current version of Django, the base class method "_create_server " has changed and now returns a ThreadedWSGIServer object. If you don't change that in your override, and still return a WSGIServer object, your test server will now act single threaded, which can make your e2e tests fail, eg in cypress or selenium.

Comment: Well spotted, thanks, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ArnaudP this is a great idea and a solution for a problem that also haunted my code. Now I'm looking for how to make this code log tracebacks too. Would be great to incorporate this into pytest-django...

Answer (score 0):

Amazing answer by Arnaud.

Speaking of brittleness, here is a slight tweak for Django 4.2 for other people:

```
. . .

def _create_server(self, connections_override):
     return ThreadedWSGIServer(
          (self.host, self.port),
          WSGIRequestHandler,
          allow_reuse_address=False,
          connections_override=connections_override,
     )
```